# How can I get a symbol below a word?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, subscripts

[image: I wanted to get theta below argmax in the middle]

I wanted to get theta below argmax in the middle .
I used the following code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,enumerate,algorithm}
\begin{document}
$\theta_i$ = $argmax_{\theta} Q(\theta, \theta_i)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) the limit only goes under the argmax when it is used in display math context, you are using `$...$` which is inline math mode, there the limit is not shown below argmax as it will disturb the line spacing.

Comment: BTW: next time please provide a full example, you are missing the document class. Besides in your formula, the two middle `$` are not needed, the `=` should also be math mode

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for an operator `\argmax` which can be defined in the following way (needs `amsmath`)

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
```

To have "theta below argmax in the middle" in inline math, you have to specify `\limits` when using it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}

\noindent Inline math: $\theta_i = \argmax\limits_{\theta} Q(\theta, \theta_i)$

\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent Displayed math

\[\theta_i = \argmax_{\theta} Q(\theta, \theta_i)\]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @egreg I could get the format of code for answers and questions by using the back-quote but same didn't work for writing a code snippet in the comment section. Could you please explain?

Comment: @MSKantulu Comments obey slightly different rules; for instance, in order to print ``\\`` you need double back quotes.

Comment: @egreg can you give any helping link for these formatting stuffs in comments? The double back quotes didn't get me on the next line

Comment: @MSKantulu Look at posts under http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code+comment